# Sorting dicom images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, dicom

I am working with lung data sets in matlab, but I need to sort the slices correctly and show them.

I knew that can be done using the "instance number" parameter in Dicom header, but I did not manage to run the correct code.

How can I do that?

Here is my piece of code:

```
Dicom_directory = uigetdir();
sdir = strcat(Dicom_directory,'\*.dcm');
files = dir(sdir);
I = strcat(Dicom_directory, '\',files(i).name);
x = repmat(double(0), [512 512 1 ]);
x(:,:,1) = double(dicomread(I));
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(x,[]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to get the DICOM header, you need to use [`dicominfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicominfo.html?refresh=true) which will return a `struct` containing each of the fields. If you want to use the `InstanceNumber` field to sort by, then you can do this in such a way.

```
%// Get all of the files
directory = uigetdir();
files = dir(fullfile(directory, '*.dcm'));
filenames = cellfun(@(x)fullfile(directory, x), {files.name}, 'uni', 0);

%// Ensure that they are actually DICOM files and remove the ones that aren't
notdicom = ~cellfun(@isdicom, filenames);
files(notdicom) = [];

%// Now load all the DICOM headers into an array of structs
infos = cellfun(@dicominfo, filenames);

%// Now sort these by the instance number
[~, inds] = sort([infos.InstanceNumber]);
infos = infos(inds);

%// Now you can loop through and display them
dcm = dicomread(infos(1));
him = imshow(dcm, []);

for k = 1:numel(infos)
    set(him, 'CData', dicomread(infos(k)));
    pause(0.1)
end
```

That being said, you have to be careful sorting DICOMs using the InstanceNumber. This is not a robust way of doing it because the "InstanceNumber" can refer to the same image acquired over time or different slices throughout a 3D volume. If you want one or the other, I would choose something more specific.

If you want to sort physical slices, I would recommend sorting by the `SliceLocation` field (if available). If sorting by time, you could use `TriggerTime` (if available).

Also you will need to consider that there could also potentially be multiple *series* in your folder so maybe consider using the `SeriesNumber` to differentiate these.

Comment: Really thank you very much ,,, but when I tried your code I got back with the following error ..

Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in project3>Load_Image_Callback (line 190)
[~, inds] = sort([infos.InstanceNumber]);

Comment: @AhmedHassaan Sorry about that! I had to alter the `cellfun` call to `dicominfo` to return a struct rather than a cell. Test it now.